# Get lines that start with number

Tags: regex, awk, grep, diff

I have a bash command `diff file1 file2`, and the corresponding output is something like:

```
74,100c74,100
<         some text
```

This is just a small subset, and of course, starting of lines in `diff` output varies widely (I know of `>, <, -, \` and chars from `1` to `9`, but there may be others, I'm not really sure). I only want output lines that start with a number from `1` to `9` (not `0`, because I'm only concerned with the positions where changes occurred, and line number won't start with `0`).

Thus, if I pipe `diff` with that command, the output should be:

```
74,100c74,100
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks...

Comment: [grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you please try following. Written based on description of OP.

```
your_command | awk '/^[1-9]/'
```

You could also use `grep` too like:

```
your_commamd | grep "^[1-9]"
```

***Explanation:***

In `awk` in case we have to use a regex to match in current line we use that regex inside `/` that's why giving `^[1-9]` means look if line starts from anything between 1 to 9 and if regex matches for current line as it's by default action printing of current line happens.

Comment: It worked (at least for the 2 commands I tried). Thank you

Comment: why use `awk` for this? `grep` is normally used for this kind of things, like: `your_command | grep "^[1-9]"`

Comment: @Luuk, I think I mentioned the same too in my solution since I got up from my system so I added a note in it, thanks.

Comment: But you did not test `your_command | grep -E '/^[1-9]/'`, because in my test it does not work ;(

Comment: @Luuk, no it shouldn't be used in that way, it should be used `"[1-9]"` manner, I am having my dinner if you want feel free to edit above or I will add it in few mins cheers.

Comment: @Luuk, added grep command now too. Ankit, will add explanation in sometime too.

Comment: @AnkitKumar, added explanation in answer now kindly take a look to it and lemme know in case of any queries here cheers.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you!